# SQL NVL function to pass multiple values

Tags: sql, oracle, erp

I have a requirement that i need to set parameter as text and for passing multiple values user can give multiple values by using comma(,)
And if user will not give any value it returns all the values....
E.g. where pha.segment1 IN (:Segment1)
Here we can paas multiple values but not null........if i use nvl here it will give error bcoz IN clause not used with nvl

Comment: Hello and welcome please check this guide : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask    , in your case you have to at least put some of your code here and clarify the problem

Comment: You have not asked a question. Please [edit] your post to clarify what the question is and include a [MRE] with **YOUR** attemts to solve the problem and the issues/errors with **YOUR** attempt.

Answer (score 1):

If you can convert a comma separated list into rows, then a normal subquery can do the job, eg if your table or data is like:

```
create table t as 
select '123,456,789' acct 
from dual
```

then you can convert to rows via

```
select substr(acct,
              nvl(lag(loc) over ( order by loc),0)+1,
              loc-nvl(lag(loc) over ( order by loc),0)-1
             ) list_as_rows
from (
   select distinct (instr(acct||',',',',1,level)) loc
   from t
   connect by level <= length(acct)-length(replace(acct,','))+1
), t

RESULT
-------
123
456
789
```

Now it just becomes

select ...
from   my_table
where  col in ( ...the select above )